# Replace slice of string python with string of different size, but maintain structure

Tags: string, python-3.x, slice

so today I was working on a function that removes any quoted strings from a chunk of data, and replaces them with format areas instead (`{0}`, `{1}`, etc...).
I ran into a problem, because the output was becoming completely scrambled, as in a `{1}` was going in a seemingly random place.
I later found out that this was a problem because the replacement of slices in the list changed the list so that it's length was different, and so the previous `re` matches would not line up (it only worked for the first iteration).
the gathering of the strings worked perfectly, as expected, as this is most certainly not a problem with `re`.
I've read [about mutable sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable), and a bunch of other things as well, but was not able to find anything on this.
what I think i need is something like `str.replace` but can take slices, instead of a substring.
here is my code:

```
import re

def rm_strings_from_data(data):
    regex = re.compile(r'"(.*?)"')
    s = regex.finditer(data)
    list_data = list(data)
    val = 0
    strings = []

    for i in s:
        string = i.group()
        start, end = i.span()
        strings.append(string)
        list_data[start:end] = '{%d}' % val
        val += 1

    print(strings, ''.join(list_data), sep='\n\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rm_strings_from_data('[hi="hello!" thing="a thing!" other="other thing"]')
```

i get:

```
['"hello!"', '"a thing!"', '"other thing"']

[hi={0} thing="a th{1}r="other thing{2}
```

I would like the output:

```
['"hello!"', '"a thing!"', '"other thing"']

[hi={0} thing={1} other={2}]
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not match both `key=value` parts using regex capture groups like this: `(\w+?)=(".*?")`
Then it becomes very easy to assemble the lists as needed.

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/QT7QBl):

```
import re

def rm_strings_from_data(data):
    regex = re.compile(r'(\w+?)=(".*?")')
    matches = regex.finditer(data)
    strings = []
    list_data = []
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
        matchNum = matchNum + 1
        strings.append(match.group(2))
        list_data.append((match.group(1) + '={' + str(matchNum) + '} '))

    print(strings, '[' + ''.join(list_data) + ']', sep='\n\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rm_strings_from_data('[hi="hello!" thing="a thing!" other="other thing"]')
```